# Trying to replace PHP String to show different on output

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am using BuddyPress with Xprofile plugin.

The string in profile is Date of Birth, I want it to display Age on the profile page output instead.

This is the default code, it will display the profile field name and then the value for that field.

```
 <dl<?php bp_field_css_class('dl-horizontal'); ?>>

            <dt><?php bp_the_profile_field_name(); ?></dt>

            <dd><?php bp_the_profile_field_value(); ?></dd>
          </dl>
```

I want it to have an exception, if a string named "Date of Birth" appears in bp_the_profile_field_name(); , then it would display string "Age" instead, but display rest of fields the same as they are.

Comment: You're wanting to change the string `'Date of Birth'` to the string `'Age'`, or at least display it that way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with buddypress, but in general, checking to see if a string is one thing and if it is display something else is fairly straight-forward. Even something like this: `bp_get_the_profile_field_name() == 'Date of Birth' ? 'Age' : bp_get_the_profile_field_name()`

Comment: I edited my post to make it a bit more clear, I tried your code, it didn't function; didnt display any fields... I am seriously new at PHP :(

Comment: I dont know this buddycode but In general you need to produce your html/xml (dl, dt, etc tags) and buddy code inside a greater php code insert in order to create buddy tags conditionally. E.g: <php> produce html, if my string equals ... then produce these buddy tags else.... html... <php>.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you should be able to see if the function `bp_get_the_profile_field_name()` returns the string 'Date of Birth', then do something appropriately.

Example using if/else block:

```
if (bp_get_the_profile_field_name() == 'Date of Birth') {
    print 'Age';
} else {
    print bp_get_the_profile_field_name();
}
```

Or through ternary operator (shorthand for if/else):

```
<?php print bp_get_the_profile_field_name() ? 'Age' : bp_get_the_profile_field_name(); ?>
```